# Error al cerrar session con token

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

me explico estoy haciendo un login con 3 perfiles ya logre que me identifique que perfil entro y sea mandado a su modulo hasta hay todo bien el problema surge cunado cierro sesion queda la pantalla en blanco y no retorna al index donde esta el formulario de login

segui un ejemplo para hacer un login y la verdad soy algo novato en esto ,espero que me puedan ayudar
este es mi login

`

```
$correo=$_POST['correo'];
$clave=md5($_POST['clave']);
require_once('Conexion.php');
$conn = Conectar();

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT  id_usuario, nombre, apellido, correo, p.id_perfil, perfil FROM usuario u INNER JOIN perfil p ON p.id_perfil=u.id_perfil WHERE u.correo=:correo AND u.clave=:clave");
$stmt->bindParam(':correo',$correo);
$stmt->bindParam(':clave',$clave);
$stmt->execute();


if($stmt->rowCount()>=1){
    session_start();
    $fila=$stmt->fetch();
    if($fila['id_perfil']==1)
        {header("Location: administrador/index.php");}
    if($fila['id_perfil']==2)
        {header("Location: aprendiz/index.php");}
    if($fila['id_perfil']==3)
        {header("Location: root/index.php");}

}
else{
     echo "<font color='red'>Datos No Validos</font>";
}
```

?>  ´

" mi archivo que cierra sesion"

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 if(isset($_GET['tk']) && isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_GET['tk']==$_SESSION['token']){
  session_destroy();
  header("Location: index.php");
 }
?>
```

se que el problema esta entre el archivo de cierre y el login ya que en el login no estoy haciendo referencia al token de cierre y en el archivo de cierre no hago referencia a los perfiles que tengo en login y la verdad no se como hacerlo espero de su colaboracion y muchas gracias

Comment: Por que no quitas el `if` en el archivo que cierra la sesión

Comment: lo que no se es como va como aclare arriba soy novato :/

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo `cerrarsesion.php` no es necesario el `if` porque solo necesitas borrar las variables de `session` aqui va un ejemplo:

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location: ../login.php");
?>
```

**EDITO**
Para evitar que el usuario pase solo con la `url` crea un archivo `seguridad.php` y lo incluyes en las paginas que no quieres que ingrese sin iniciar sesion, he aqui lo que deverias implementar el dicho archivo:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['idPerfil'])){//preguntamos si la variable esta vacía
    header("location: ../login.php");//salimos del directorio de donde este con ../ y redireccionamos al logearce
}

?>
```

En esta parte de tu código puedes definir las variables de esa manera:

```
if($stmt->rowCount()>=1){
    session_start();
    $resultado = $stmt->get_result();
    $fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
    /*  Definiremos las variables de SESSION que requieras utilizar en este caso usare idPerfil, nombre, apellido, puedes declarar mas si lo deseas */
    $_SESSION["idPerfil"] = $fila['id_usuario'];
    $_SESSION["nombre"] = $fila['nombre'];
    $_SESSION["apellido"] = $fila['apellido'];

    //para poder utilizar su contenido es suficiente por ejemplo echo $_SESSION["apellido"];

    if($fila['id_perfil']==1){
        header("Location: administrador/index.php");
    }
    if($fila['id_perfil']==2){
            header("Location: aprendiz/index.php");
    }
    if($fila['id_perfil']==3){
            header("Location: root/index.php");
    }

}
else{
     echo "<font color='red'>Datos No Validos</font>";
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64077/discussion-on-answer-by-kevin-error-al-cerrar-session-con-token).